# Change of variables in Lebesgue differentiation theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Lebesgue differentiation states that:

> If $f\in L_{loc}^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then
>   $\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}f(y)dy=f(x)$

I am considering if the following is true:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{|B(0,r)|}\int_{B(0,r)}f(x-t)dt=f(x)$$

Comment: Note that $\int_{B\left(0,r\right)}f\left(x-t\right)dt=\int_{B\left(x,r\right)}f(y)dy$ by the Change of Variables Theorem and $\left\lvert B\left(0,r\right)\right\rvert=\left\lvert B\left(x,r\right)\right\rvert$ since Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.

Comment: @user71352 I can't see why the first equality is true